# Java setNull() for int in JDBC Prepared Statement being ignored - mysql inserts zero instead

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to upload a int value to my database table , that may be null. I have the following code:

```
ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table1 (COL1) VALUES(?)");

if( int_val == null) {
    ps.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
}
else {
    ps.setInt(1, int_val);
}
```

The int_val variable is a java.lang.Integer, so it can have a null value. The code does enter the "int_val == null" if loop, so we know that int_val is indeed null. The table it is inserting into has COL1 defined as:

```
intVal INT NULL COMMENT ''
```

so it can take the null value. However, when it processes the query it inserts a zero into the COL1 column instead of null. In my actual code, it is able to enter varchar columns as null with no problems at all.

The MySQL jars i am using with my glassfish installation are:

```
com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar –
```

Any ideas whats going on here? Am I doing something very obviously incorrect?

Comment: And the column isn't defined as `DEFAULT 0`?

Comment: Have you made sure that the actual value of `int_val` is `null`? (Unrelated - variable names should *not* include underscores. It should be called `intVal` according to the coding conventions).

Comment: Which version of the MySQL JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: The column is defined as: `intVal` INT NULL COMMENT ''

Comment: Have you tried using `java.sql.Types.INTEGER` explicitly?

Comment: I've also checked that the value is null - it is entering the if statement correctly. The MySQL jars i am using with my glassfish installation are: com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar and mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar

Comment: Just as a test have you tried `INSERT INTO table1 (COL1) VALUES(NULL)`?

Comment: I've tried using java.sql.Types.INTEGER explicitly and that didn't work. I've also tried inserting the NULL explicitly into the INSERT statement, and that didn't work either! I have been using a MySQL workbench ERR diagram to generate the create table code. It adds these lines of code at the top - I've no idea what they do, but maybe they affect things?  `SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';`

Comment: Make sure your column is not "NOT NULL" , And you can also try ps.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);

Comment: It really is looking like a driver issue.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, but have you verified that `int_val` is actually `null`? BTW: What is the type of `int_val`?

Comment: int_val is actually null - it enters the appropriate part of the IF loop. It is also of type java.lang.Integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that along the line somewhere converting the values to and from JSON had messed up the null values and placed zeroes there.

In the code I was testing, there was a number of calls, and it was the first call which was placing the null through as zero, while I had fixed the subsequent places where it could be updated from.

Thanks for the help - feel v. stupid now!

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, unless you have defined a default value for the column and considering that the column accepts `NULL`; you can change your `INSERT` statement to be like below to insert `null` into the column. This is strictly `MySQL` solution but I am not sure if there is any similar way present in `Java` to achieve the same.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (COL1) VALUES(NULL)
```

(OR)

```
INSERT INTO table1 (COL1) 
SELECT NULL FROM dual;
```

Comment: Hi Rahul - I need to do it via JDBC as part of a larger query, so I don't think that will be practical

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use an alternative jdbc-driver e.g. MariaDB just to make sure that the problem is not within the driver?

https://downloads.mariadb.org/connector-java/1.2.2/

This driver should be compatible to your mysql-server.